# How to create an upload page (front side)

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I would like to have a methodology for creating a functionality. When the user is connected, he will can access to a new page. In this page he will have the possibility to submit some fields like : a title, a description, an image and some tags.

I have thought several things :

- I have to create a little plugin which will display the form
- I have to create a custom post types with a the fields above

Am I right ?

Then the goal is to manage all the submissions (admin side). The admin will decide if this custom post type will be published.

What is the way for validate, insert into the bdd and display the submissions in the admin dashboard ?

Comment: Have you already searched the site? There're several questions around that topic.

Comment: Seeing that it's a specific need, I I preferred asking a question.

Comment: Your research efforts are actually [a requirement](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask), especially for a topic [discussed as often as this one on our site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=upload%20front). What have you tried already? What didn’t work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) plugin. You can create a form for your user to submit, and include a field for uploads.

Less work on your side and a kick-ass plugin.